# How can I seperately display a view's exposed filter and its content in page.tpl?

Tags: 7, theming, views, debugging

Using `<?php dpm($node) ?>` I found the exposed filter, `$...->view->exposed_widgets`, however I'm not sure how to display it. I tried `<?php echo $node->view->exposed_widgets; ?>` but that returns nothing.

`<?php dsm($form); ?>` and `<?php dpm($form); ?>` both give

> Notice: Undefined variable: form in include() . . . page.tpl.php

Are those deprecated? I see them mentioned sometimes but they've never worked for me.

The only place I see the form in `<?php dpm($page); ?>` is `['content']['system_main']['main']['#markup']`, and that can't be separated, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, why you want to doing via coding. Create views exposed filter as blocks and place in the sidebar and by default the content will load in the right side of the content area. Now you will get filters and content separately...